# Git over SSH Server in Windows, cannot find shared libraries

Tags: windows, git, ssh, putty

I was to setup an SSH Server to Host my Git Repository to my local area network. I followed this [tutorial by TimDavis](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/) hoping that I would be able to make a secured Git Repository.

I tested my connection using Putty and it was successful. My only problem was I cannot run "git" command in the console. Then I tried cloning my repository, and this was the error that outputed:

```
/usr/bin/git-upload-pack.exe: error while loading shared libraries: 
libiconv2.dll: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

Also when I ran "git" command in the Putty Bash that was connected to the SSH Server, this was the error I encountered:

```
/usr/bin/git.exe: error while loading shared libraries: pthreadGC2.dll: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I seems that all my problem was about the missing libraries but I don't know how to solve it. I am using Windows 7 as an Operating System.

Thanks

Comment: git works fine for me using cygwin ssh.

Comment: hhm.. going to try it.. i used msysgit.. thanks..

Comment: I'm trying to do what you are and am using the same site and windows 7 too.  When I try to clone, I get connection refused, remote hung up and tried a plink and got your error.  Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this error too. I tried copying not just git.exe but the corresponding dlls (libiconv, etc...) from the git bin directory to the CopSsh bin directory and it went away.

Comment: That works but I copied not only the contents of the bin folder but also the git-core contents. I copied all of them to the Bin folder of SSL/ICW.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that - you need the git upload and other exes.  One more thing.  I didn't like copying the files, so what I did was I undid the copy and added the bin directories to the git path.  So far, so good.  I describe how I did it in my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows/2440745#2440745

Answer (score 6):

As explained here: http://christopherpeplin.com/2013/01/cygwin-git-https/ the sasl libraries and the ca-certificates are missing. Install them by running the setup of cygwin, and installing libsasl2 and ca-certificates packages (the first is support for SSL and the second the root certificates that will be used for SSL authentication).

Comment: Thanks!  This helped with my problem using HTTP access.  However, I don't know if it solves the OP's problem with SSH access.

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you are talking about the following article:
http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/

Then try to modify the path. Just add add the following lines into \home\.bashrc :
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/d/programs/Git/bin:/cygdrive/d/programs/Git/libexec/git-core

Where d/programs/Git is a d:\programs\Git -- is a path to msysgit installation

Answer (score 2):

I also found that git submodule update would fail on Cygwin due to another broken dependency, where you need to install the gettext package as well.

http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/Re-shared-object-file-not-found-with-git-submodule-update-init-recursive-in-Cygwin-64-bit-td104123.html

Comment: git submodule was failing and this showed me the message.