# Git clone using ssh - can't find repository

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit

I'm trying to setup a Git server on Windows 7, using CopSsh, PuTTY and msysgit.  I'm having problems cloning a repository using ssh.

If I use a regular directory path, it works:

```
$ git clone ~/vc/git/depot/test.git/ /c/dev/es/app
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/dev/es/app/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Ssh, doesn't work.  I've tried an different paths without success.

```
$ git clone ssh://steve@test:4837/~/vc/git/depot/test.git/ /c/dev/es/app
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/dev/es/app/.git/
fatal: '~/vc/git/depot/eastApp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I followed the instructions from here: http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/

Any clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the path wrong...

```
git clone "ssh://steve@test:4837/Program Files (x86)/ICW/home/steve/vc/git/depo/test.git" 
 /c/dev/es/app/
```

worked.