# git clone on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I have installed an SSH server on Windows Server 2008, and initialized a git repo.

I'd like to clone this on my dev environment, so that I can commit and push changes.

Having trouble figuring out the path; here's what I see in every example:

```
home$ git clone ssh://myuser@server/path/to/repository
```

That's great and all, but I don't understand how to use that for windows.  This seems wrong to me:

```
home$ git clone ssh://myuser@server/Program Files (x86)/Apache/Apache/htdocs/myrepo
```

How does the path really work in windows?

Comment: What SSH server did you use? Copssh?

Comment: Also what tutorial did you follow

Comment: The spaces in your path definetly cause problems.

Comment: Using freesshd, perhaps I should switch to Copssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have followed the tutorial [Setting up a Msysgit Server with copSSH on Windows](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/), I confirm your "`Program Files (x86)`" can work.

See for instance SO answer "[Git clone using ssh - can't find repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433049/git-clone-using-ssh-cant-find-repository/2434967#2434967)":

```
git clone "ssh://steve@test:4837/Program Files (x86)/ICW/home/steve/vc/git/depo/test.git" 
          /c/dev/es/app/
```

You will find other path examples in "[How to stop git via ssh on windows from resolving the wrong path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092583/how-to-stop-git-via-ssh-on-windows-from-resolving-the-wrong-path)".

Using Openssh rather than plink.exe is easier though: see "[Setting up a Git server with Windows Server 2008](http://www.shannoncornish.com/blog/2009/04/git-server-windows-2008/)".

As the [OP JohnZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/883374/johnz) mentions in the comments:

> Looks like this depends a little bit on the ssh server you use.
>   I installed CYGWIN, which has openSSH installed.
>   To clone it, I did this:

```
git clone "ssh://root@192.168.1.1/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/myrepofolder"
```

Comment: So using the ssh syntax, it will automatically go to C:/?  what if I want to have a repo on another drive letter?

Comment: @JohnZ: you should be able to specify that drive in the path: Example for drive '`e`': `/e/path/to/repo.git`

Comment: oh!! that's slick. very cool.  Is that documented anywhere that you know of?  I didn't see it in any of the like 6 tutorials I read through or the git clone man page.

Comment: @JohnZ: good question. I was looking for a definitive source of documentation on that topic.

Comment: Looks like this depends a little bit on the ssh server you use.  I installed CYGWIN, which has openSSH installed.  To clone it, I did this: git clone "ssh://root@192.168.1.1/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/myrepofolder"

Comment: @JohnZ: good point. I have included your comment in the answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks for all the help. Such a relief to have a little bit of assistance when I need it.