# How do I git clone from a Windows machine over ssh?

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I can do `ssh windowsmachine` from Linux to access a Windows machine, and from there I can `git init --bare foo.git`, telling me `Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/unhammer/foo.git/`

but how do I clone that from the unix side?

```
$ git clone ssh://windowsmachine:foo.git
Cloning into 'foo'...
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax

$ git clone ssh://windowsmachine:C:\\Users\\unhammer\\foo.git
Cloning into '\Users\unhammer\foo'...
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax

$ git clone ssh://windowsmachine:/foo.git
Cloning into 'foo'...
fatal: ''/foo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and similar messages for `/C:/Users/unhammer/foo.git` and
`/C/Users/unhammer/foo.git` and `/Users/unhammer/foo.git`.

Note the double single-quotes:

```
fatal: ''/Users/unhammer/foo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
```

This doesn't happen when I try to `git clone linuxmachine:/some/path/that/does/not/exist.git`, then git uses single single-quotes. (Maybe that's the issue, git-for-windows or something applying extra quotes?)

Comment: This depends a little bit on the ssh server you use. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050564/7976758. Try `git clone ssh://windowsmachine/Users/unhammer/foo.git`.

Comment: It's the builtin Windows 10 one (Setting→Apps & Features→Manage optional features→Add a feature→OpenSSH server). There was a bit off [fiddling](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/how-to-install-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-server/) to get it set up, but I can `scp -r windowsmachine:/Users/unhammer.foo.git`, while `git clone ssh://windowsmachine/Users/unhammer/foo.git` fails (`''/Users/unhammer/foo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository`).

Comment: Indeed, it happens because the default windows shell interprets single quotes as literals, and git always sends single quotes around it's arguments to the remote shell

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest solution is to [change the default Windows OpenSSH shell to bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#configuring-the-default-shell-for-openssh-in-windows). You can do this easily from powershell on the Windows machine:

```
powershell
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

You may have to restart OpenSSH on the Windows machine and/or kill existing ssh connections from the client before it takes effect. Now you can clone without any extra -u option:

```
git clone ssh://windowsmachine/c/Users/unhammer/foo.git
```

(and if you previously specified uploadpack/receivepack, remove them from .git/config)

Comment: Nice, worked for me, but had to run powershell as admin.

Comment: It seems easier to me to just use regedit and set the value. That way I can see if the value was already set and save it if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Following [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834304/how-do-i-git-clone-from-a-windows-machine-over-ssh#comment94526196_53834304)'s link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050564/7976758 I found a reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323826/69663 with a workaround to the quoting issue. Here's what I did:

On Windows, open Git Bash and, in my homedir:

```
echo 'git-receive-pack "$@"' >grp.sh
echo 'git-upload-pack "$@"' >gup.sh
```

On Linux, clone specifying upload-pack:

```
git clone -u '"C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe" gup.sh' ssh://windowsmachine/c/Users/unhammer/foo.git
cd foo
git config remote.origin.uploadpack '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" gup.sh'
git config remote.origin.receivepack '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" grp.sh'
```

So the repo path is the one that Git Bash shows (`/c/Users/$username/$repo`), no colon anywhere.

---

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1082 seems related.

Comment: This is the best answer here. With more modern versions of Git on Windows, this should be `git receive-pack` (i.e. the `receive-pack` subcommand of git) and `git upload-pack`.