# How to get the SSH url of a git repo on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, git-push

I created a `git` repo on Windows Server machine, let's call it `remote_server`, using:

```
cd C:\Users\me\myapp
git init --bare myapp.git
```

After that, the `myapp` folder contains the `myapp.git` folder.

Then from my `local_desktop`, running Windows 11, I want to push to the `remote_server`:

```
cd D:\myapp
git remote add server ssh://me@remote_server/C/Users/me/myapp/myapp.git
git push server main
```

But I am getting this error:

```
fatal: ''/C/Users/me/myapp/myapp.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried different SSH URLs for the remote repo:

```
git remote add server ssh://me@remote_server/C/Users/me/myapp
git remote add server ssh://me@remote_server/C:/Users/me/myapp/myapp.git
git remote add server ssh://me@remote_server/C:/Users/me/myapp
```

I got the same error.

Please help me find the right SSH URL.

Comment: Try `ssh://me@remote_server:/C/Users/me/myapp` or `me@remote_server:/C/Users/me/myapp`. But I'm not sure if it works when the remote server is Windows.

Comment: Same error, in both cases

Comment: I'd try this simple method: connect to ssh (with an ssh client, not git), `cd` to the repo, get the output of `pwd` and use it in the URL path like: `me@remote_server:/blah/blah/blah`.

Comment: The issue I think is that the path on Windows is: `C:\Users\me\myapp`.  I tried `me@remote_server/C:\Users\me\myapp` without success.

Answer (score 0):

I got the way forward from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54106128/2814580).

After changing the default Windows OpenSSH shell to bash, I was able to run this successfully:

```
git remote add server ssh://me@remote_server/C/Users/me/myapp/myapp.git
git push server main
```