# Able to connect to private SSH server via CMD/git bash, but unable to git clone, git push or git pull

Tags: git, networking, ssh

I'm running a private SSH server(running openSSH) and able to remotely log into it. Problem comes when I want to use git clone. 
I created an empty repository on the windows 10 server machine as, **C:\Users\myUserName\testSSH.git**. Then on my other computer I'm trying to

```
[git clone ssh://myUserName@HSGA0057/~/testSSH.git] and getting:
```

> fatal: ''myUserName/testSSH.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Any ideas how to solve this?

More info: I already created key authentication and able to SSH from CMD without password. Username and host machine is properly spelled and exist. 
I think the problem comes from openSSH server/client and also using git

Comment: Try the real path instead of `~`. `~` is resolved to `$HOME` of the current user. It should be the home in the remote server.

Comment: Thanks I've been trying the following,                                                                   
git clone ssh://myUserName@HSGA0057/C:/Users/myUserName/testSSH.git            and git clone myUserName@HSGA0057:C:/Users/myUserName/testSSH.git         and no sucess

Comment: Did you run `git daemon` in the remote repository. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon

Comment: @ElpieKay git-over-ssh doesn't require git daemon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git clone on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050338/git-clone-on-windows)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+%22does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository%22+%22C%3A%2F%22

Comment: None solved my issue. I can log in via ssh without any issue and I can even see the git repo I want to clone. But again typing "git clone ssh://myUserName@HSGA0057/C:/Users/myUserName/testSSH.git / git clone myUserName@HSGA0057:C:/Users/myUserName/testSSH.git" does seem to work

Comment: You just typed the same bad URLs instead of trying the linked answer.

Comment: the URLs from the linked answer have same structure as the ones im typing

Comment: @phd thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the problem persists with:

- the [latest Git 2.25](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
- the URL using the full path with:

  ```
  git clone ssh://myUserName@HSGA0057/C/Users/myUserName/testSSH.git
  # or
  git clone ssh://myUserName@HSGA0057/c/Users/myUserName/testSSH.git
  ```

Meaning, without `C:/` but with `C/`.