# Clone works, remote push doesn't. Remote repository over copssh

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit, windows-7-x64, copssh

I've "setup-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows", following Tim Davis' [guide](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/) and I was now learning how to use the git commands, following Jason Meridth's [guide](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jason_meridth/archive/2009/06/04/git-for-windows-developers-git-series-part-2.aspx), and I have managed to get everything working fine, but now I can't pass the push command.

I have set the server and the client on the same machine (for now), win7-x64.

Here is some info of how things are set up:

```
CopSSH Folder     : C:/SSH/
Local Home Folder : C:/Users/rvc/
Remote Home Folder: C:/SSH/home/rvc/          # aka /cygdrive/c/SSH/home/rvc/
git remote rep    : C:/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git # empty rep
```

At '/SSH/home/rvc/.bashrc' and 'Users/rvc/.bashrc':

```
export HOME=/cygdrive/c/SSH/home/rvc
gitpath='/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin'    
gitcorepath='/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core'
PATH=${gitpath}:${gitcorepath}:${PATH}
```

So, cloning works (everything bellow is done via "Git Bash here" :P):

```
rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code
$ git clone ssh://rvc@192.168.1.65:5858/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/code/myapp/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code
$ cd myapp

rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://rvc@192.168.1.65:5858/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://rvc@192.168.1.65:5858/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git (push)
```

Then I create a file:

```
rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ touch test.file

rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ ls
test.file
```

Try to push it and get this error:

```
rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ git add test.file

rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master
trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'C:\Users\rvc\bin\plink.exe' '-batch' '-P' '5858' 'rvc@192.1
68.1.65' 'git-receive-pack '\''/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git'\'''
git: '/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

"git: '/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'." .. what?!

**EDIT:**
RAAAGE!!

I'm having the same problem again, but now with ssh:

```
rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push
trace: built-in: git 'push'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' '-p' '5858' 'rvc@192.168.1.65' 'git-receive-pack '\''/
SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git'\'''
git: '/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've tried GUI push, and shows the same message.

```
git: '/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Pushing to ssh://rvc@192.168.1.65:5858/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Here's the currents .bashrc:

C:\Users\rvc.bashrc (I think this is used only by cygwin/git bash):

```
export HOME=/c/SSH/home/rvc

gitpath='/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin'

gitcorepath='/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core'
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=${gitcorepath}

PATH=${gitpath}:${gitcorepath}:${PATH}
```

C:\SSH\home\rvc.bashrc (.. and this is used when git connects via ssh to the "remote" server):

```
export HOME=/c/SSH/home/rvc

gitpath='/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin'

gitcorepath='/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core'
export GIT_EXEC_PATH=${gitcorepath}

PATH=${gitpath}:${gitcorepath}:${PATH}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Some additional info:

```
rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ ssh -p 5858 rvc@192.168.1.65 git-receive-pack /SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git
git: '/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ git push --receive-pack='git receive-pack' ssh://rvc@192.168.1.65:5858/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git --a
ll
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 202 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://rvc@192.168.1.65:5858/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Has this did the trick??

git push is running 'git-receive-pack', and it should be 'git receive-pack' ?

My git version is 'git version 1.7.0.2.msysgit.0'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

stupid fix (this changed /SSH/home/rvc/.gitconfig):

```
rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"

rvc@RVC-DESKTOP /c/code/myapp (master)
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 246 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://rvc@192.168.1.65:5858/SSH/home/rvc/myapp.git
   680f32e..2da0df1  master -> master
```

Answer (score 1):

1) most often cause of this prob - Open a Git Bash window and type `echo $HOME` – ensure it is set to `/c/SSH/Home/<user>/`. If it is not – enter `export HOME=/c/SSH/home/<user>`

2) try the GUI interface [same prob?]

Answer (score 1):

Found the [answer](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/)...

> GIT_SSH
>
> ```
> If this environment variable is set then git fetch and git push will
> ```
>
> use this command instead of ssh when
>   they need to connect to a remote
>   system. The $GIT_SSH command will be
>   given exactly two arguments: the
>   username@host (or just host) from the
>   URL and the shell command to execute
>   on that remote system.
>
> ```
> To pass options to the program that you want to list in GIT_SSH you
> ```
>
> will need to wrap the program and
>   options into a shell script, then set
>   GIT_SSH to refer to the shell script.
>
> ```
> Usually it is easier to configure any desired options through your
> ```
>
> personal .ssh/config file. Please
>   consult your ssh documentation for
>   further details.

I just had to delete the GIT_SSH var from the windows environment variables.

I've had it set because I was following Tim Davis' guide, but without using TortoiseGit,
and the guide says to point the variable to TortoisePlink (step 4.4), so I assumed I had to
pointed to plink.exe :P. O well.. moving to the next problem...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I was also getting the error

```
git: '/pathToRepo/myRepoName.git' is not a git command See 'git --help'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

the git config command worked for me.

```
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"
```

I am running MSysGit-1.7.3.1