# git over ssh, push doesn't work

Tags: git, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIT: clone works, remote push doesn’t. Remote repository over copssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736862/git-clone-works-remote-push-doesnt-remote-repository-over-copssh)

I cloned a git repo over ssh. After some work it now worked.

```
git clone "ssh://user@server.com/repo.git"
```

But now, when I try to push to the server (which is mine)

```
git push origin  master
```

I get the error:

```
git: '/repo.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

The repo is installed on windows with COPSSH and msysgit. 
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: could you paste the .git/config  file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
One has to change the config file:

```
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"
```

As written here:
[GIT: clone works, remote push doesn't. Remote repository over copssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736862/git-clone-works-remote-push-doesnt-remote-repository-over-copssh/4669390#4669390)

Now it works like a charme!

Answer (score 3):

Open `.git/config` file and see what is set for url under `[remote "origin"]`. If it is not the correct url, point it to the `ssh://user@server.com/repo.git`. From the error message, it looks like the url is not setup properly.

Comment: There is the right url in the config file...