# Windows git/ssh/cygwin: git: '/oneplant.git' is not a git command

Tags: windows, git, ssh, amazon-ec2, cygwin

So I've been working at getting a Windows 2008 EC2 instance up and running, along with git as a remote repository to push my project to the server live. Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Create Windows EC2
2. Install git & cygwin (with openssh)
3. Add the required ports, firewall exceptions.

At this point, I can SSH into my server remotely and init repo's just fine. I'm now using [this blog post](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) to setup my remote repository. Followed these steps:

Locally:

1. `git clone` project from another source
2. `git remote add production ssh://[USER]@[SERVER]/oneplant.git`

Remotely:

1. create the post-receive hook and chmod it with +x:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   GIT_WORK_TREE=C:/inetpub/wwwroot git checkout -f
   ```

Lastly, I call `git push production +master:refs/heads/master` locally and login, it returns with this command:

```
    git: '/oneplant.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've been trying to search the web for this but I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong, hopefully someone can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: A shot in the dark here: Try `git remote -v` to see if the remote was added with the correct URL. If not, try removing it (`git remote rm production`), and then add it again with double-quotes around the URL: `git remote add production "ssh://[USER]@[SERVER]/oneplant.git"`

Comment: Thanks @MikeMorearty, unfortunately it seems to have the correct path, I tried removing/adding it with double quotes again and still receiving the same error. Is there a git log that is kept? would be useful seeing what command sent actually caused the error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2736862/179675 seems very similar, and has some magic incantations to fix. I'm not posting this as an answer because it's just another shot in the dark.

Comment: I've also tried to do it in a different repository completely just in case the oneplant.git folder caused some weird behaviour, removing the .git does nothing and I still get the error... for some reason its thinking anything after the server (IP in this case) is trying to be a git command :/ hmmmm