# GIT - cannot push because my path is interpreted by git

Tags: git, ssh

on my server "sourcecode" i do :

```
cd /home/AyamJ/pbGIT
git --bare init
```

on my local notebook i do :

```
git push AyamJ@sourcecode:/home/AyamJ/pbGIT master
```

i got error:

```
git:'/home/AyamJ/pbGIT' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
fatal: the remote end hung up enexpectedly
```

on my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host sourcecode
user AyamJ
port 31313
Host localhost
user Dell
port 22
```

why that path is interpreted by git?

== UPDATE ==

i have 2 server (by git --bare init) "localhost" and "sourcecode"

i do

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git push sourcecode:/home/AyamJ/pbGIT master

got 

trace: built-in : git 'push' 'sourcecode:/home/AyamJ/pbGIT' 'master'
trace: run_command : 'ssh' 'sourcecode' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/AyamJ/pbGIT'\'''

AyamJ@sourcecode's password:
git: '/home/AyamJ/pbGIT' is not a git command. See  'git --help'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

and

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git push localhost:/home/Dell/pbGIT master

got 

trace: built-in : git 'push' 'localhost:/home/Dell/pbGIT' 'master'
trace: run_command : 'ssh' 'localhost' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/Dell/pbGIT'\'''

Dell@sourcecode's password:
Everything up-to-date
```

both server has similar cygwin and package.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a config file, then you should use:

```
git push sourcecode:/home/AyamJ/pbGIT master
```

After that, try a:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git push sourcecode:/home/AyamJ/pbGIT master
```

And check out "[GIT: clone works, remote push doesn't. Remote repository over copssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736862/git-clone-works-remote-push-doesnt-remote-repository-over-copssh)":
Adding a `--receive-pack='git receive-pack'` could help.
Or at least, a `git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"`.
And check if you have a [`GIT_SSH` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737826/6309) set.

Make sure to try it with the latest Git release to see if the issue persists.

Comment: i do GIT_TRACE=1, got trace:build-in:git 'push' 'sourcecode:/home/AyamJ/pbGIT' 'master', trace:run_command: 'ssh' 'sourcecode' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/AyamJpbGIT'\'''

Comment: @kreamik You can edit your question with a full and complete trace of that command. And try first a `git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"`.

Comment: i have add that global config .. and what else clue i should add more?

Comment: "Everything up-to-date": it seems your push has worked, hasn't it (For `Dell`)? Is there any right issue (difference in protection) between `Adam` and `Dell` repo directories and parent directories? Why using `sourcecode:` for both? Shouldn't you `localhost:` for Dell (if I read your ssh config file properly)?

Comment: the only different is : user AyamJ is created by net user "AyamJ password /add /yes and mkpassd -l -u AyamJ >> /etc/passwd" and Dell is really local user. And you're right sourcecode for dell is localhost

Comment: @kreamik ok, did you check to protection on /home/AyamJ/... vs. /home/Dell/...? As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425811/git-ssh-authentication/13428529#13428529

Answer (score 1):

### Use a relative path

With a relative path it'll probably work:

```
git push AyamJ@sourcecode:pbGIT master
```

I'm not sure of the reason, but testing with abs paths it fails for me so that is probably the/part-of-the error for you. **But** that isn't the normal way to use git.

### Be normal

First ensure the ssh config is setup such that you don't need usernames and passwords i.e. this should work:

```
(notebook)$ ssh sourcecode
...
(server)$
```

On the local git repo - create a [remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) that points at the remote server's repository:

```
(notebook)$ git remote add sourcecode:pbGIT origin
(notebook)$ git push
```

It is deliberate that last command has no arguments - with a recent version of git it'll give an error message like so:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
   git push --set-upstream origin <current branch name>
```

The error message is telling you how to make it so you can push/pull with no arguments, therefore execute that command. With an older version of git the command is the same, there's just no error message. After executing this command, e.g.:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

from this point forwards it's not necesssary to use arguments with `git push` and `git pull`

### Do it the other way around

When starting from scratch, or if the remote repository already exists, it's actually easier to do these things the other way around

```
(notebook)$ ssh sourcecode
...
(sourcecode)$ mkdir x.git
(sourcecode)$ cd x.git
(sourcecode)$ git init --bare
(sourcecode)$ exit
(notebook)$ git clone sourcecode:x.git
Cloning into 'x'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Note that above, the remote git repository has been created in a folder named `whatever.git` - this is merely a convention to identify git folders/repositories, it doesn't have any special meaning, though it's likely to be in all examples.

If after that you take a look in the `.git/config` file on you'll see something like this:

```
(notebook)$ cd x; more .git/config
    [core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0 
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = sourcecode:x.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Which indicates that the remote origin points at the sourcecode server, and the one branch that exists, `master`, tracks the remote `origin`.