# scp from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, path, file-transfer, scp

I am running a putty client on a Windows machine to connect successfully to a Linux box. Now I want to be able to copy a file from the Linux machine under the path `/home/ubuntu/myfile` to `C:/Users/Anshul/Desktop` on my local computer. The user at the Windows machine is `anshul`. I am giving the following command on putty but it is not working:

```
scp /home/ubuntu/myfile ip_address_of_windows_machine:C:/Users/Anshul/Desktop
```

I think the path for the Windows machine is wrong. Please help as I have banged my head on a large number of forums but none seem to give correct path for Windows server. Don't suggest alternate options like `WinScp`

Comment: So what are you running for an ssh *service* on Windows? The correct answer would depend on your answer to this question.

Comment: The phrase "Not working" is the absolute least useful thing you can say when asking for help.  WHAT isn't working? What results do you actually get?  Are there any error message?  If so, include them in your post.

Comment: Try 'ssh -v ip_address_of_windows_machine dir' If you can't ssh to the box, then you can't scp to it either.  The '-v' option will give some feedback about how it is trying to connect and help figure out whether it is the ip address, the sshd server on the windows box, etc...

Comment: `scp hello.txt Administrator@WINDOWS_MACHINE_IP:hello.txt`

This copied the file to `C:\Users\Administrator\hello.txt`.

Comment: @emoblazz has the best answer if you don't want to install third party things. you basically make sure you have your username and @ before

Answer (score 149):

This one worked for me.

```
scp /home/ubuntu/myfile username@IP_of_windows_machine:/C:/Users/Anshul/Desktop
```

Comment: This is the only true answer to this question.

Comment: In my case, the command worked but not completely. The following message is shown: ssh: connect to host <ip_address> port 22: Connection refused.

Comment: @AlexJavarotti The error you got might be caused by the firewall setting.

Comment: So I realize that the question was not about MacOS, but on a Mac, I found both the form suggested in this answer worked, but also a variant that dropped the initial '/'. So something like ...:C:/Users/...etc. Not terribly different, but worth noting I suppose.

Comment: @ChouW "*Connection refused*" is not a firewall issue. It's simply that the service is not started, and thus is not bound to the port 22.

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad can't remember since it was 2 years ago. I thought maybe the firewall in the windows os block the request and we'll get the "connection refused" error

Comment: What worked for me in 2023, first we need to setup Windows properly:
- we need to configure openssh daemon by appending `AllowUsers <our_user>` line to the `sshd_config` file, it is located in C:\ProgramData\ssh\ or it should be present in the network tab after you have enabled ssh server

- after editing it restart ssh server by typing `net stop sshd` and `net start sshd` in the console as privileged user

- now we are set and in order to send files from linux to our windows machine, the syntax is as follows: scp file.txt username@username:/C:/Users/username/Desktop (cont. below)

Comment: On windows our hostname is usually the same as our username so thats why we have to specify destination like that, and after that we should be able to authenticate with our password and file should go through.

Comment: Ok, too bad I cant post an answer, those steps above are meant for openssh server installed from official Microsoft repos, link here https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases . Also dont use either openssh from the `Optional features` settings tab or msi installer and get the zip, extract the folder to program files and run assorted powershell script to install, I couldn't get the msi or optional features ones to work. You will also have to add system path variable to the openssh  folder so you can access the ssh command from your shells).

Answer (score 97):

Download `pscp` from [Putty download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), then use it from Windows Command Line `CMD` as follows:

```sh
pscp username_linux_machine@ip_of_linux_machine:/home/ubuntu/myfile.ext C:\Users\Name\Downloads
```

Copying starts once you enter the password for the Linux machine.

Comment: This command didn't work for me until I added the -scp flag.

Comment: `scp` that ships with Windows 10 had problems finalizing larger transfers (weird error "<filename>: Is a directory", leaving a partial file although download was complete). `pscp` seems to do be working just fine!

Comment: I love it when something works the first time.  Thanks.

Comment: Pay attention if you use an ssh key generated by `ssh-keygen` you need to convert that to the Putty-specific format using `PuTTYgen`.

Answer (score 70):

Try this, it really works.

```
$ scp username@from_host_ip:/home/ubuntu/myfile /cygdrive/c/Users/Anshul/Desktop
```

And for copying all files

```
$ scp -r username@from_host_ip:/home/ubuntu/ *. * /cygdrive/c/Users/Anshul/Desktop
```

Comment: Notice the "/cygdrive/c" in the path? This will work after installing CYGWIN. Still is a great suggestion!

Comment: On Windows you may also opt to use pscp (part of the PuTTY package, or can be downloaded separately)
http://www.putty.org/

Comment: @SalvadorValencia ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-20:~$  scp try.sh Administrator@XXXX:/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Desktop
ssh: connect to host XXXX port 22: Connection refused
lost connection

Comment: I am on Linux server and want to copy to windows server ! Also will cygwin listen on port 22 ? or else which port should we opened as my windows server is in aws ec2 instance

Comment: How to copy a large file using this?

Comment: @AshishKarpe this looks like the command ran but it encountered router/firewall issues. Do a "telnet XXXX 22" and see if it opened the port. If not then stackoverflow should help you solve it with iptables or the windows firewall, for example.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, but instead of cygwin I am using freeSSHd. When I scp my file from linux to the windows server, my linux machine says scp is successful, but I cannot see the file in the folder I mentioned. Any help on this?

Comment: Default in April 2018 Update for Win10 - https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-openssh-client-installed-by-default-in-april-2018-update/

Regarding the destination, you can also just use "."to drop the file in your current working directory: scp username@from_host_ip:/home/ubuntu/myfile .

Answer (score 51):

Access from Windows by Git Bash console (also works for CMD and PowerShell):

```sh
scp user@ip:/dir1/dir2/file "D:\dir1\dir2"
```

Comment: Finally some advice that works, thanks!

Comment: Nice! This worked well and is very simple.

Comment: path to be not given in inverted commas, apart from that answer is correct. Thanks.

Comment: in order to use a domain account to authenticate to the Windows Server the syntax is: scp file.ext ad_user@domain.subdomain.com@windows_IP:file.ext  ( yes 2 @ symbols !! )

Comment: You might get a permission error if you're trying to paste something in C drive, so you might want to paste file in some other directory.

Answer (score 15):

You could use something like the following

```
scp -r linux_username@linux_address:path/to/file path/to/local/directory
```

This will copy `file` to the specified local `directory` on the system you are currently working on.

The `-r` flag tells `scp` to recursively copy if the remote `file` is a directory.

Answer (score 9):

Windows doesn't support `SSH/SCP/SFTP` natively. Are you running an SSH server application on that Windows server? If so, one of the configuration options is probably where the root is, and you would specify paths relative to that root. In any case, check the documentation for the SSH server application you are running in Windows.

Alternatively, use `smbclient` to push the file to a Windows share.

Comment: »Windows doesn't support SSH/SCP/SFTP natively.« Neither does Linux or any other OS. It always needs a service for that.

Comment: @Joey - Number of times I've seen a Linux distro intended to connect to the internet but not have SSH/SCP/SFTP preinstalled... never? If you don't think Linux or macOS support those things natively, then you're either clueless or the debate is over what the word "natively" means.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I'm pretty sure Ubuntu doesn't have SSH server installed by default. SSH client yes, but not server.

Comment: @BrunoFinger - I just installed Lubuntu a few days ago, and I can confirm it didn't have an SSH server by default. But Lubuntu is a very bare bones install of Ubuntu - I intentionally chose it because of how minimal its install footprint was. I think most of the other pre-built configurations have it already installed, and in any event, getting the ssh server installed was a single line command (off the top of my head, I think it was `sudo apt-get install sshd`.) Seconds later I was able to SSH in from another computer.

Comment: @Joey Nonetheless, the answer is useful, because Windows ships the sshd service as an optional install even in the Professional SKU. (I wonder if Enterprise enables it by default). It would be easy to overlook, since so many other platforms enable this service by default, so it bears mentioning. One has to go to "Settings/Apps/Optional features" and install "OpenSSH Server". Also the service has to be started, and should be set to automatic launch.

Answer (score 4):

For all, who has installed GiT completly with "Git Bash": You can just write:

```
scp login@ip_addres:/location/to/folders/file.tar .
```

(with space and DOT at the end to copy to current location). Than just add certificate (y), write password and that's all.

Comment: That's simple and great solution for people trapped in Win env, especially that git bash is easily available in portable mode, for those working without admin rights. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had to use pscp like above Hesham's post once I downloaded and installed putty.  I did it to Windows from Linux on Windows so I entered the following:

```
c:\ssl>pscp username@linuxserver:keenan/ssl/* .
```

This will copy everything in the keenan/ssl folder to the local folder (.) you performed this command from (c:\ssl).  The keenan/ssl will specify the home folder of the username user, for example the full path would be /home/username/keenan/ssl. You can specify a different folder using a forward slash (/), such as

```
c:\ssl>pscp username@linuxserver:/home/username/keenan/ssl/* .
```

So you can specify any folder at the root of Linux using `:/`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't working because c:/ or d:/ is totally wrong for **linux just use /mnt/c or/mnt/c**

**From your local windows10-ubuntu bash use this command:**

**for download:**
(from your remote server folder to d:/ubuntu) :

```
scp username@ipaddress:/folder/file.txt /mnt/d/ubuntu
```

Then type your remote server password if there is need.

**for upload:**
(from d:/ubuntu  to remote server ) :

```
scp /mnt/d/ubuntu/file.txt username@ipaddress:/folder/file.txt
```

Then type your remote server password if there is need.
note: I tested and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**To send a file from windows to linux system**

*scp path-to-file user@ipaddress:/path-to-destination*

Example:

```
scp C:/Users/adarsh/Desktop/Document.txt root@127.0.0.1:/tmp
```

keep in mind that there need to use forward slash(/) inplace of backward slash(\) in for the file in windows path else it will show an error

> C:UsersadarshDesktopDocument.txt: No such file or directory

.
After executing scp command you will ask for **password of root user in linux machine**.
There you GO...

**To send a file from linux to windows system**

*scp -r user@ipaddress:/path-to-file path-to-destination*

Example:

```
scp -r root@127.0.0.1:/tmp/Document.txt C:/Users/adarsh/Desktop/
```

and provide your linux password.
only one you have to add in this command is **-r**.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @Hesham Eraqi suggested, it worked for me in this way (transfering from Ubuntu to Windows (I tried to add a comment in that answer but because of reputation, I couldn't)):

```
pscp -v -r -P 53670 user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/data/genetic_map/sample/P2_283/* \\Desktop-mojbd3n\d\cc_01-1940_data\
```

where:

`-v`: show verbose messages.
`-r`: copy directories recursively.
`-P`: connect to specified port.
`53670`: the port number to connect the Ubuntu server.
`\\Desktop-mojbd3n\d\genetic_map_data\`: I needed to transfer to an external HDD, thus I had to give permissions of sharing to this device.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to copy files from Linux to Windows using SCP without password by ssh:

1. Install sshpass in Linux machine to skip password prompt
2. Script

   `sshpass -p 'xxxxxxx' scp /home/user1/*.* testuser@x.x.x.x:/d/test/`

Details:

```
sshpass -p 'password' scp /source_path/*.* windowsusername@windowsMachine_ip:/destination_drive/subfolder/
```

Answer (score 0):

Open bash window. **Preferably git bash**.
write

**scp username@remote_ip:/directory_of_file/filename 'windows_location_you_want_to_store_the_file'**

Example:

Suppose your username is **jewel**

your IP is **176.35.96.32**

your remote file location is **/usr/local/forme**

your filename is **logs.zip**

and you want to store in your **windows PC's D drive forme folder**
then the command will be

**scp jewel@176.35.96.32:/usr/local/forme/logs.zip 'D:/forme'**

**Keep the local file directory inside single quote.

Answer (score -10):

Try this:

```
scp /home/ubuntu/myfile C:\users\Anshul\Desktop
```

Comment: Yes it worked fine.  Since I am running this on my local Windows PC and I am running SCP it knows about my C:\ drive.  I am not running this command from the Linux box, I am running it from my Windows PC.

Answer (score -13):

If you want to copy paste files from Unix to Windows and Windows to Unix just use filezilla with port 22.