# SCP to local dir

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, scp

ssh command:

```
scp ~/local/app/file.txt /C:/myfolder
```

error message:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/C:/myfolder/': No such file or directory
```

What is incorrect or what is the syntax for the local dir?

Comment: where is /C:/myfolder??

Comment: and from where you are running this command?

Comment: So I'm running the command via ssh on my local computer trying to get the files from the remote server.

Comment: your local computer running windows or linux?

Comment: its running windows. I'm using putty.

Comment: You can use winscp in windows for copiying file from remoter server

Comment: can I not use normal scp?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235778/scp-from-linux-to-windows

Comment: well thanks... I still couldnt get scp working but whatevs. I'm using psftp instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pscp.exe in your windows machine then you can try this command

pscp.exe user@remoteserver:~/local/app/file.txt /C:/myfolder

else you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

The command should be modified as below

```
scp ~/local/app/file.txt C:/myfolder
```

Loose the '/' in front