# Remotely backup SQL Server Docker container Using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, docker, database-backups, powershell-core

I have a SQL Server on a docker container (`microsoft/mssql-server-linux`)
I want to Backup the database remotely using Powershell command.

So The final result will be that a `.bak` file would be added to the container.
Does anyone knows if it is possible, and how?

Answer (score 1):

yes! `microsoft/mssql-server-linux` is based on **ubuntu 16.04** and its possible to use `scp` from inside container to your host!use `docker exec -it {container_id} bash` to access your container terminal! 
after creating `.bak` file with this guid:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-2017

the file is inside your container!use `scp` to copy over ssh!

here is a hint about how to `scp` from linux to windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712656/4708874

Comment: Can I use backup command without getting bash access to inside of the container, my goal is to use rest request to the listening sql container, to backup.

Comment: I am getting the following "bash: mysqldump: command not found"

Comment: for the first comment, you can but you need to write a web service or you can use an open source project here: https://github.com/arut/nginx-mysql-module

Comment: mysql != mssql. As such, I wouldn't expect a backup command for the former to work on the latter.

Comment: oh sorry!these days I work on different projects with different RDBMS and I mixed them up! I edited my answer thank you @BenThul

Answer (score 0):

Backing up the database should work no differently just because the SQL Server is running in a container. That is, issuing a `backup database [yourDB] to disk = '«some file path»';` will work. Now, whether that file path is internal to the container or external (i.e. you are using a persistent volume) depends on how you started the docker instance.