# Is it possible to download file or folders from AWS Linux EC2 instance to local Windows 10 machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having one Linux Ec2 instance on AWS and my local machine is Windows 10 (64-bit).

I want to download some files or folders from Ec2 to location windows machine.

I am not sure whether it is possible or not? if yes, how we can do that.

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235778/scp-from-linux-to-windows this answers your question

Comment: The two most obvious ways would be SSH or AWS CLI.

Comment: I found the command to copy the file but how i can copy the complete folder?

Answer (score 1):

Got the command to Copy from Windows to Linux.

1. First you need to install putty (putty-64bit-0.74-installer.msi) on your windows machine
2. The Command is as follow it will copy the folder(e.g. DokerAutomationResult) to the windows machine from AWSLinux machine.

   `pscp -r ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/home/ubuntu/DokerAutomationResult ./`

   `[pscp -r ubuntu@(ipAddress):(locationOfLinuxFileLocation /(locationToCopyInWInodws) ]`

For better Understanding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sc0f-sxDJy0&ab_channel=Liv4IT

Answer (score 1):

I tried this it worked for me.
Download https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/ its an Enhanced terminal for Windows.

You can link your EC2 instance directly via SSH its pretty simple to set up. Just follow the instuctions they've given. Once linked, its super easy to export, import, create files and folders all via mobaxterm.

folders in mobaxterm:

[image]

Comment: @RBT just a use a bang `![folders in mobaxterm][1]`

Comment: ohh! Nice trick. I wasn't aware. Very slick solution. Now I can make the edits at a much faster pace. Thank you so much Jeremy for sharing this info. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to download files from ec2 linux instance to local system.

You can use `scp -i key user@ip add:/file` location which you want to download.

`.` will download file in your current location on local system