# GIT central repository on Windows network share

Tags: windows, git, version-control, permissions, network-share

Our company is looking at setting up a central GIT repository.  As we are using Windows, we've been looking at using a network share solution, based on the following articles [here](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/) and [here](http://freshbrewedcode.com/derekgreer/2012/02/19/hosting-a-git-repository-in-windows/).

However, after thinking about this I have some questions.  (Warning - I'm a noob at GIT)

1. It seems that this solution might allow developers to cause problems with the repo, by allowing them to map to the drive and play with the files (outside of the GIT client).  Is there a way to prevent this?  Or do I misunderstand something here?
2. If your using network shares, does the GIT installation on the server actually have a purpose?  Or is it just clients pushing back and forth from the share.
3. Any advice on a best solution would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What worked best before was an install of gitolite on a linux vm. This way you have many admin options. I highly recommend gitolite.

Comment: Yes - gitolite is what I use... actually more recently gitlab which has gitolite integrated.  And I certainly recommend this configuration too if the OP is open to a non-Windows option.

Comment: all it takes is running one Linux vm. shouldn't be a problem in any organization.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in that with the windows share (although easy), you sacrifice some functionality.. permissions and server-side hooks come to mind.

Here's another question that might help: [How to setup and clone a remote git repo on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308952/how-to-setup-and-clone-a-remote-git-repo-on-windows)

Or this: [Setup a Git server with msysgit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check them out.