# Are git bare repositories on network drives a bad idea for collaboration?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-remote

We are a small team of 3-5 developers that use around 20-30 Visual Studio projects.

Until now we didn't use any source control method.

We decided to give git a try.

We have been playing with success locally having our personal repositories to track our development.

Now i want to start the real use for us which is to develop things in parallel by using git properly.

I wanted just to create a bare repository for each project and store it a local file server.

I dont want to go online on github or any other system, nor i want to create a git *nix box to act as server.

Is this a terrible idea?

Comment: I've used this technique before on Windows, since git is able to push, pull, and clone using file-system URIs. Whether or not it's a "bad idea", well, perhaps that's debatable. Why don't you want to use a hosting company like GitHub or Bitbucket? Do you have good backups of your network drive in case it breaks? Also, good job on finally using source control! I would never do development without it.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it a little, maybe it wouldn't be so bad if your network drive breaks, since your developers all have a clone of the repo on their machines anyway. But still, if all of your machines are located in the same building, if there's a fire or something that destroys your building and all of your equipment, you're in big trouble without an off-site backup.

Comment: Backup is not an issue from so many ways. I dont want to go outside since the source is closed (enterprise code) and i dont want to go to a paid service yet. Also regarding catastrophic failure of the shared repo, its one of the things i like in git..Just recreate it from a clone..

Comment: possible duplicate of [GIT central repository on Windows network share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533042/git-central-repository-on-windows-network-share)

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple times here on SO.

Comment: I was asking if this is a bad idea not exactly how i would go about and implement it.As i understood from the other relative questions, this is the way to go.