# How to link Jenkins to local repository?

Tags: git, jenkins

My path to repository is somewhat like this:
C:\MY FOLDER\Projects\git-repo

Jenkins returns error code **returned status code 128:**

Comment: Giving the path like file:///C:/MY FOLDER/Projects/git-repo also did not help.

Comment: Try using `ssh` to pull the code on jenkins

Comment: It's in my local network mapped drive.. I think ssh does not apply  here

Comment: I guess this question would help you with the nework problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308952/how-to-setup-and-clone-a-remote-git-repo-on-windows