# Git Copssh no longer free, what are the alternatives, and how to setup a local Git server on windows

Tags: git, ssh

I wanted to install a local GIT server on windows so I went to tortoise GIt but the installation guide link to Copssh is no longer valid, The Copssh has turned it into commercial,

So I'm actually beginner, and I have only been using Git as a client for a while, and I wanted to have a local repository on another computer in a local network, the OS is Windows 7.

during the writing of this question, I've done a small trick I went to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
and looked over the latest answer and found this git server called http://gitstack.com/, It looks neat but I don't know yet if it will also require copssh or what,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclamer : I am the gitstack founder.

GitStack works out of the box and does not require copssh (or any other stuff). GitStack authentication has been implemented using apache so a simple username/password will work (no need to generate a ssh key).

You will be able to use your regular git client to connect to your git server.

Comment: I've used GITstack at the end and it works just fine for a local network, thanks alot for such amazingly simple tool, please don't stop and try to add some features, cheers