# Is it possible to host git on Windows7

Tags: git, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setup a Git server with msysgit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows)

Is it possible to host git on Windows7?

I want social coding  with my friends.
Because i don't want use github.com, I wonder how to make git server on windows7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Here are some git server You can use,  [Bonobo Git Server](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/wiki)

Comment: You can try Git Candy, A Git platform based on ASP.NET MVC. Source on:http://github.com/Aimeast/GitCandy, Demo on: http://git.53wb.com/

Answer (score 1):

While I *am* a die-hard Git aficionado, for this particular case I would rather recomment [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org) with its [`fossil server`](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/reference.wiki#server) or `fossil winserv` modes or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) with its [`hg serve`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/hgserve) mode.

Also note that while @cen pointed you to [the right question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1482824/720999) (I also voted to close this answer as exact duplicate), if by "social coding" you mean something like code sprint where a group of people sits on a LAN you might as well not mess with setting up complicated schemes as Git is able to access repos on Windows machines via shares using the `file://` schema.  I mean, if you want to access repo `C:\devel\project` on machine `thebox`, you can turn that folder into a share, say, `project` and then access it form other machines via `file:////thebox/project`.  Usually you will need to first visit that share in Windows Explorer to make Windows authenticate you and cache your credentials.  And of course the hosting machine has to have authentication properly set up as well.  Which kind of reverts us back to my first point anyway. ;-)