# Using GIT repository for existing MonoTouch project

Tags: git, version-control, xamarin.ios, repository

I would like to add a GIt repository for my existing MonoTouch project. My project is on Mac machine but i would like to create the main repository on a Windows machine in same network. Is that possible? 
I came across many docs adding Git to existing project but on the same machine. I would like to set up a Windows machine as my GIt server and commit my changes from my Mac machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setup a Git server with msysgit on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows)

Comment: is the windows filesystem (or part of it) available as a network share on the mac? please answer so that we know if we need to tell you about setting up ssh and stuff or if we can skip that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. I would recommend another private bare repo on bitbucket too. Make sure that the path to the repo on the windows machine is viewable as a share. Then just add the remote on your Mac repo with

```
git remote add origin file:///\\servername\sharename\subpathtogitrepo
```

this assumes you don't have any remotes set up yet. If you do, substitute `origin` with something else like `winremote`.

Comment: Do i need to clone it on my mac machine? I dont want to use bitbucket. Can you point me to a doc/tutorial explaining these things.